# Openpyxl - print two values in different columns without replacing, then change row

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to print two values in adjacent columns without replacing previous values, and then change row. And repeat.

When i write it like this:

```
ws.cell(row = ws.max_row+1, column = 1).value = value13
ws.cell(row = ws.max_row+1, column = 2).value = value14
```

It changes rows to early, for obvious reasons. How would one solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `ws.max_row+1` with a counter that you increment after each run.

```
counter = 1
while True:
    ws.cell(row = ws.max_row+counter, column = 1).value = value13
    counter +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can best to this with a cell's offset method:

```
cell_with_value = ws.cell(ws.max_row, column=1)
print(cell_with_value.value)
cell_from_next_row = cell_with_value.offset(row=1)
cell_from_next_row.value = "a new value"
```